# Send data with putExtra and getExtra

Tags: android

I have a question about send data between two activity files. Below code is a part of pdf viewer application.

**Main Activity**

```
private void init() {
    lv_pdf = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_pdf);
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    fn_permission();

    lv_pdf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PdfActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", i);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("Position", i + "");
        }
    });
}
```

`onItemClick()` method sends data from main activity to second activity(`PdfActivity.java`) with `putExtra`.('position' is a index of pdf files)

**Second Activity**

```
private void init() {
    pdfView = (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PdfFile.pdf");

    if (pdfFile.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(objIntent);
    }

    displayFromSdcard();
}

private void displayFromSdcard() {
    pdfFileName = MainActivity.fileList.get(position).getName();

    pdfView.fromFile(MainActivity.fileList.get(position))
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .load();
}
```

In second activity, 'position' gets data with `getintExtra()` method and default value is 0. `position` variable is used for rendering pdf files.

**Problem:**

'Default value 0' is the first index number. It means the last saved file on the SD card. But if I clicked a pdf file in app chooser, no matter which file is clicked, the last saved file is always opened.

How do I change default value to open the pdf file that I clicked?

Following code is manifest.xml file about second activity file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".PdfActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.pdffilefromsdcard.MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**What I've tried:**

I made an additional variable `positionStr` that data type is string and put it into file path, but application was stopped suddenly when I launched it.

Comment: Where are you using the position variable in the second activity?

Comment: @NikhilGupta I added code about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `position` variable anywhere in your code. The code line

`File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PdfFile.pdf");`

always gets the same pdf file, therefore you should appropriately pass the `position` parameter to this line to open the desired file.

Comment: How do I pass `position` variable in the code? File() method uses `java.io` parameter so I can't push it.

Comment: Since 'position' variable is an index of files, create an array of pdf file names if possible e.g String[] pdfNames. Then pass it in your code as this: File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pdfNames[position]);

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I doesn't work for me...I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you post the crash report that you receive when you do what you did in your 'What İ have tried' section? May ne you are missing ".pdf" extension in your 'positionStr' String.

Comment: `File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pdfNames[position] + ".pdf");` Is this right? My logcat displays nothing now :(

Comment: I declared `String positionStr;` and changed the code line to `File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), positionStr + ".pdf");`. But nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you assigning any value to your String positionStr anywhere in your code?

Comment: I added this line: `positionStr = String.valueOf(position);`

Comment: I do not think this will give the true result.. First define pdf file names in a String array e.g `String[] pdfNames={"PdfFile1.pdf", "PdfFile2.pdf","PdfFile3.pdf"};` place as much pdf file names as you need. Then declare the File object as `File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pdfNames[position]);`